# Is there a way to use/bring up a console when viewing templates (using Django Debug Toolbar)?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-debug-toolbar

I love [Django Debug Toolbar](https://github.com/robhudson/django-debug-toolbar) and I mainly use it just to see the variables passed to the template (shown under the "Templates" tab on the right menu).

But the variables are shown like this

```
{'form': <django.forms.models.OrderForm object at 0x1033937d0>}
{'csrf_token': <django.utils.functional.__proxy__ object at 0x103394cd0>}
{'perms': <django.contrib.auth.context_processors.PermWrapper object at 0x103393510>,
 'user': <django.utils.functional.SimpleLazyObject object at 0x10339b690>}
{'debug': True, 'sql_queries': '<<sql_queries>>'}
{'LANGUAGES': '<<languages>>',
 'LANGUAGE_BIDI': False,
 'LANGUAGE_CODE': 'en-us'}
{'MEDIA_URL': ''}
{'STATIC_URL': '/static/'}
{'TIME_ZONE': 'EDT'}
{'messages': <django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage object at 0x10339bb90>}
{'request': '<<request>>'}
```

For variables like `form`, `messages`, and `request`, this list isn't very informative. Is there a way to dig deeper and view all the possible attributes for these kinds of variables? Kind of like [playing with the API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial01/#playing-with-the-api) using `python manage.py shell` for templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `django-debug-toolbar` but if you install [`django-extensions`](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) you can use the [`runserver_plus`](http://packages.python.org/django-extensions/runserver_plus.html) command. This replaces the default exception/debug screen with werkzug debugger which gives you access to an interactive shell.

[Check out a tutorial here](http://michaeltrier.com/2008/06/22/werkzeug-debugger-in-django/)

Comment: Hmm I actually already have `runserver_plus`, how would I trigger an exception. Normally I would drop an `assert False`, but most of my views are generic, so it doesn't go through `views.py`.

Is there any way to trigger the exception screen from the template?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more efficiently using Django-Debug-Template: https://github.com/t0ster/django-debug-template

Just load template debugger by {% load debug %} first.

Then drop a shell from templates for a particular variable by {{ var|ipdb }}

Comment: I spent so much time to find this :D