# Howto automatically set_trace in Django while debugging

Tags: django, debugging

Django debugging is kind of repeat work when I put a magic line "import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace();" in the source code, which not just annoying but also bad for code standard.

I just wondering whether there is a way automatically set_trace while encounter any errors

Comment: I prefer seeing the exception page first because I only need the full power of the debugger when the planets align to cause a ridiculous bug . But here's a reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13174412/python-start-interactive-debugger-when-exception-would-be-otherwise-thrown

Comment: check answer of this stackoverflow answer:
[werkzug debugger][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902640/is-there-a-way-to-use-bring-up-a-console-when-viewing-templates-using-django-de